# ”Wasted time" shown by React.addons.Perf.printWasted

Tags: reactjs

In this code, `printWasted` prints `Wasted time` when `add` button is clicked.

```
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            count: 10
        };
    },
    onClick: function() {
        Perf.start();
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1}, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                Perf.stop();
                Perf.printWasted();
                Perf.printDOM();
            }, 0);
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var messages = [];
        for (var i = this.state.count; i > 0; --i) {
            messages.push({id: i, body: 'message:' + i});
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>add</button>
                <div>
                    {messages.map(function(message, index) { return <Message key={index} message={message.body} />})}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
var Message = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {}
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.message}</div>
        );
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/koba04/0xnLdh7j/1/

```
(index) Owner > component Wasted time (ms) Instances
0   "App > Message" 1.3059999982942827  1
```

[image: result of printWasted]

I think `printWasted` prints only components that didn't actually render anything.

In this code, According to the result of `printDOM`, It seems all Message components mutate the DOM.

Why does `printWasted` print the `Wasted time`?
What is this `Wasted time`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior was fixed in v0.14.

A related pull request is this.
https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/4683

In v0.14, There is no `Wasted time`.

https://jsfiddle.net/koba04/4xozxrj7/

```
var Perf = React.addons.Perf;
var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            count: 10
        };
    },
    onClick: function() {
        Perf.start();
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1}, function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                Perf.stop();
                Perf.printWasted();
                Perf.printDOM();
            }, 0);
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var messages = [];
        for (var i = this.state.count; i > 0; --i) {
            messages.push({id: i, body: 'message:' + i});
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.onClick}>add</button>
                <div>
                    {messages.map(function(message, index) { return <Message key={index} message={message.body} />})}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

var Message = React.createClass({
    componentWillMount: function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {}
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>{this.props.message}</div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The React docs say that `printWasted` prints the time spent in components that did not *change* their render tree- i.e., re-rendering them was a waste of time.